# can't add a new data to my simple JSON ($scope.customers)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm just started to learn about angular.js so I'm really a newbie. I don't know if there is a syntax problem or any other simple problem but I just couldn't make that happen.

I've started with [Dan Wahlin's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnXO-i7944M). And I will use Rodrigo Branas' book.

```
<html ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('customersApp', []);

        app.controller('CustomersController', function($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
                {"id": 1, "name": "Yusuf", "age": 18},
                {"id": 2, "name": "Ahmetcan", "age": 17},
                {"id": 3, "name": "Ender", "age": 20},
                {"id": 4, "name": "Batuhan", "age": 16},
            ];

            $scope.add = function (name){
                $scope.customers.push(angular.copy(name));
                delete $scope.name;
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="nameTxt"/> <input ng-click="add(nameTxt)" type="submit"/>
    <table ng-controller="CustomersController">
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:nameTxt">
            <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
            <td>{{cust.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    You are looking for: {{nameTxt}}
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works perfect except $scope.add function. The thing I'm try to is get nameTxt and add that to $scope.customers.

I think that the problem is between JSON data structure and the data that I'm trying to add. But just don't know to how to solve that. Already, thanks..

EDIT: [Here is the example of Rodrigo..](http://ideone.com/td8BQf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is where I use the "ng-controller" parameter. I've already defined that inside of  tag but inputs are not inside of the table as that must be.

I've changed 3 line and problem solved.

```
<body>
```

to

```
 <body ng-controller="CustomersController">
```

So deleted the ng-controller parameter from table and edited $scope.add function as below.

```
$scope.add = function (name){
                $scope.customers.push({"name": name});
            };
```

I don't know why angular.copy doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have the input out of scope of controller and also you have to **push** an object of the same type of **customers** list. You have to calculate the **Id** of the item accordingly.

I have made a simple example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9gwyjok/)

The Html

```
<div ng-controller="CustomersController">
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="nameTxt" />
<input ng-click="add(nameTxt)" type="submit" />
<table >
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:nameTxt">
        <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>You are looking for: {{nameTxt}}</div>
```

The Code

```
var app = angular.module('customersApp', []);

app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Yusuf",
        "age": 18
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ahmetcan",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Ender",
        "age": 20
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Batuhan",
        "age": 16
    }];

    $scope.add = function (name) {
        $scope.customers.push({"id": 5, "name": name, "age": 99});
    };
});
```

Comment: Same conclusion but 1 min too late. Here the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/2Bg5paMbQVVZD92gupyU?p=preview

Comment: I would also add to be sure that your controller wrap all the functions you have defined in it in the HTML. In your case the the add(nameTxt) was outside of your controller div but Max corrected it in his demo.

Comment: I've just realized that is not about the JSON, It's all about where I defined ng-controller="CustomersController". After I define this parameter inside of <body> tag, problem solved..

Comment: @Max According to stackoverflow I need to wait 2 days to mark my answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

```
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="nameTxt"/> <input ng-click="add()" type="submit"/>

$scope.add = function (){
     $scope.customers.push({"id":$scope.customers.length,"name":nameTxt,"age":"---fill---"});
};
```

Comment: I really need that much code? When I add manually angularjs allows me to add without id and age..

Comment: why not? and what is the difference?

Comment: how do u get `cust.name` and `cust.age` if u put like this `$scope.customers.push(angular.copy(name))` ?

Comment: I will just get the name.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
$scope.add = function (name){
                $scope.customers.push({'id':"",'name':name,'age':""});

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="customersApp"> 
<input type="text" id="name" ng-model="nameTxt"/> <input ng-click="add(nameTxt)" type="submit"/>
    <table ng-controller="CustomersController">
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:nameTxt">
            <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
            <td>{{cust.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    You are looking for: {{nameTxt}}
</div>

    var app = angular.module('customersApp', []);

    app.controller('CustomersController', function($scope){
        $scope.customers = [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Yusuf", "age": 18},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Ahmetcan", "age": 17},
            {"id": 3, "name": "Ender", "age": 20},
            {"id": 4, "name": "Batuhan", "age": 16}
        ];

        $scope.add = function (name){
        $scope.customers.push({"id":'',"name":name,"age":''});

        };
    });
```